# Insecure Reponse on https access with ExpressJS/NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I keep having this recurring issue on a custom site that I built over wamp.

I followed instructions on how to generate a self-signed certificate and private key for ssl. Then I use, nodejs/expressjs to create an https server for which to use a web api for the data on my site. I am then employing angularjs to display the data.

Now the confusing part is that sometimes, it works on Google Chrome. However, it definitely fails on firefox, opera and Microsoft Edge.

On the angularjs file i have this:

```
testControllers.controller('summoner-by-name', ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', function($scope, $http, $resource) {
$scope.summonerName = {text: 'abc'};    
$scope.items = regions; 
$scope.submit = function ()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
            data = {"summonerName": $scope.summonerName.text, "region": $scope.items.selectedOption.name, "PID": "000"};
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://localhost:3030/custom_Project',
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Content-Length": data.length
                    },
                    data: data 
                }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.posts = response.data;
                });
    }, 1000);
}
}]);

...
```

On the node js file, i have this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://custom_site.com');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});

var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('C:/wamp/www/custom_Project/ssl_certs/private.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/wamp/www/custom_Project/ssl_certs/public.crt'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/cacert.pem'),
};

app.post('/custom_Project', function (req, res) {

...

}

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3030);
```

The following are the messages that I receive on the console when trying to retrieve data from the nodejs/expressjs server:

Microsoft Edge:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3030/custom_Project. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Opera (and occasionally on Chrome):

> OPTIONS https://localhost:3030/custom_Project net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

I'm under the assumption its because of the certificate being self-signed but I could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I've decided to try out some suggestions to see if my issue can be fixed. So far, these are what I've tried but they haven't solved the issue for me yet:                                                                                                           1. I added cors module through npm;  2. I've added an .htaccess file to my root folder that allows access-control-allow-origin with *;  3. I've edited httpd.conf to include Access-control-allow-origin;

Comment: I'm experiencing the EXACT same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the issues that I had.

For firefox and opera, I tracked the errors on the network tab on the developers tool. The request was not going through the node js script because of the certificate issue. So, using these browsers, I navigated to https://localhost:3030/custom_Project.

A prompt informed me that the site was not trusted and to navigate to it, I had to add it to the trusted sites list. After doing that, I ran the ajax post call and it successfully showed me the results.

Edge, however, has not given me any luck. It has an error on the top left corner saying that the site was not trusted and I couldn't do it the same as for firefox, opera and chrome.